# помогите с выделением input:checked

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать так, но не работает

```css
/* fix for codepen */

div#options {
  width: 200px;
}

.ty-control-group.ty-product-options__item.product-list-field.clearfix {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* fix for codepen */

span.colors_block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

span.colors_block input {
  opacity: -1;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

span.size_block {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.38);
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 19px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.size_block input {
  position: relative;
  opacity: -1;
  height: 19px;
  width: 30px;
  /*  margin: -19px 0 0 0; */
  top: -21px;
  left: -5px;
}


/* блок с размером и цветом */

div.size_block,
div.colors_block {
  float: right;
  width: 123px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="options">
  <div class="cm-picker-product-options ty-product-options" id="opt_7">

    <div class="ty-control-group ty-product-options__item product-list-field clearfix" id="opt_7_9">
      <label id="option_description_7_9" for="option_7_9" class="ty-control-group__label ty-product-options__item-label">
                Цвет:
            </label>
      <div class="colors_block">
        <span id="36" class="colors_block" style="background: green;">

                    <input type="radio" id="9_36" class="color" style="" name="9" value="36" checked="checked">
                </span>
        <span id="37" class="colors_block" style="background: #bdbdbd; ">

                    <input type="radio" id="9_37" class="color" style="" name="9" value="37">
                </span>
        <span id="38" class="colors_block" style="background: rgb(189, 189, 189); display: none;">

                    <input type="radio" id="9_38" class="color" style="" name="9" value="38">
                </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ty-control-group ty-product-options__item product-list-field clearfix" id="opt_7_8">
      <label id="option_description_7_8" for="option_7_8" class="ty-control-group__label ty-product-options__item-label ">
                Размер:
            </label>

      <div class="size_block">

        <span id="31" class="size_block" style="">
                    <span class="name_size">S</span>
        <input type="radio" class="size" id="8_31" style="" name="8" value="31" checked="checked">
        </span>

        <span id="32" class="size_block" style="">
                   <span class="name_size">M</span>
        <input type="radio" class="size" id="8_32" style="" name="8" value="32">
        </span>

        <span id="33" class="size_block" style="">
                    <span class="name_size">L</span>
        <input type="radio" class="size" id="8_33" style="" name="8" value="33">
        </span>

        <span id="34" class="size_block" style="">
                   <span class="name_size">XL</span>
        <input type="radio" class="size" id="8_34" style="" name="8" value="34">
        </span>

        <span id="35" class="size_block" style="">
                <span class="name_size">XLL</span>
        <input type="radio" class="size" id="8_35" style="" name="8" value="35">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

тут [демо](http://codepen.io/axell/pen/PppdKz)

Comment: Так а проблема то в чём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h2>Checkbox</h2>
<div class="colors">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="color-red"/>
    <label for="color-red" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: red"></span> Red
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="color-green"/>
    <label for="color-green" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: green"></span> Green
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="color-blue"/>
    <label for="color-blue" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: blue"></span> Blue
    </label>
</div>
<div class="sizes">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="size-s"/>
    <label for="size-s" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: grey" data-size="S"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="size-m"/>
    <label for="size-m" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: grey" data-size="M"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="size-l"/>
    <label for="size-l" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: grey" data-size="L"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<h2>Radio group</h2>
<div class="colors">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" id="color-radio-red" name="color"/>
    <label for="color-radio-red" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: red"></span> Red
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" id="color-radio-green" name="color"/>
    <label for="color-radio-green" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: green"></span> Green
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" id="color-radio-blue" name="color"/>
    <label for="color-radio-blue" class="label-checkbox">
        <span style="background-color: blue"></span> Blue
    </label>
</div>
```

Стили

```
h2
  font: bold 1.15em/1 Arial
  margin-top: 35px

.colors, .sizes
  width: 100%
  padding: 15px
  border: 1px solid #ccc
  margin-bottom: 25px


 input.checkbox
   //display: none
   &:checked + .label-checkbox
     & span
       opacity: 1

 .label-checkbox
   position: relative
   margin-right: 15px
   font: .8em/1 Arial
   & > span
     opacity: .5
     &:after
         content: ' '
         display: inline-block
         width: 20px
         height: 20px
     &[data-size]:after
       content: attr(data-size)
       text-align: center
       color: #fff
       font: .9em/1 Arial
   &:hover, &:focus
     cursor: pointer
```

[Вот набросал пример по быстрому))](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqqNdw)

Comment: спасибо! отличный пример))